# How do i write a terminal script to setup ubuntu for me instead of spending days every time?

Tags: command-line, programming, scripts

From what I understand I can make a text file with all commands same as I would type in terminal, make it executable and run it.

Would running `sudo mysetup.sh` or `mysetup.txt` be OK so not typing PW hundreds of times?.

Can I use geddit not vi its too hard to use vi for me, I'm new / old man

I need to learn basics of shell scripting any help links appreciated.

I know to write terminal commands and make the file executable, but i cn't do simple stuff like put a line break inbetween my echo statements.

Problem is I have install Ubunutu nearly 50 times now, every time I have to re-do all my terminal work
sudo update
sudo apt-get install gimp
etc ect about 100 lines of code every time, if I could just save a script it would be brilliant.

I need to learn basics,
how to make it tell user what script is doing, ( i know echo but not paragraphing it?)  also I not sue if i shud be writing sudo before every command or just sudoing the script when running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a command script with editor vi or vim.
Files shall be executable. Make them with   "chmod a+x File"
Put your scripy in directory where system path is located. 
In Terminal you find path with : echo  $PATH.

Comment: Is there a way of putting paragraphs in?

Comment: I use echo "Installing fail2ban" but so cluttered fast wud be nice for paragraphs so each step can be seen, my friend wants the script too as its designed to install essentials like gimp, wireshark etc and setup security like ufw etc